# Why can I open .iso files with Engrampa on one computer but not another?

Tags: fedora, iso, archive

I have Fedora 30 installed on two computers with different packages installed. The major difference is that one is x86_64 and the other is i686.

On the x86_64 system, I can read and extract files from .iso files. But on the i686 system I cannot with an error message "Archive type not supported."

Is there some package that I'm missing between the two that provides support for reading CD images with Engrampa?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing cdrtools (or cdrkit) package. 
I have experienced the same error in arch and after reading the bug report https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48571 I installed cdrtools and archive manager (engrampa) can now open iso files.